# Connect a device to a Worklight Server

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

im Using Worklight 6.0.0 with dojo
I have a samsung s2 to test my worklight apps, but when i tried to invoke any HTTP adapter
 like:

```
var options = {
    onSuccess : mostrarMensajePos,
    onFailure : mostrarMensajeNeg,
};

var invocationData = {
    adapter : "LoginAdapterCoopeservidores",
    procedure : "probando",
    parameters : []
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
```

The log cat always returns :

```
[myURL/apps/services/api/WorklightApp/android/query] exception. 
{"message":"INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11",
"name":"INVALID_STATE_ERR","code":11}
```

the adapter were deployed on a my Worklight server on a WebSphere. but in the android emulator runs correctly.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that if you run it on the emulator it connects correctly but if you run it on a device it fails? If so, what Android version is the emulator, and what Android version is the device? And, is the device able to reach the Worklight server?

Comment: both are 4.0.3 and ,yes, i can access to my worklight server from my samsung

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error (DOM Exception 11) probably has nothing to do with adapters. According to this site, [the error means that you are trying to use an object that no longer exists, and that it most likely means you have an error in your HTML code, either you have a tag that is not properly closed, or you have a typo.](http://designbyjeeba.blogspot.com/2011/04/dreaded-invalidstateerr-dom-exception.html)